# Why does the below sentence have a falling intonation?

Tags: pronunciation, speaking, sound

Sentence:

> Ja, hier in Bremen ist alles so teuer.

What is the rule that makes this sentence with a falling intonation?

Comment: Could you give us a bit of background? What exactly do you mean by falling intonation? Just the fact that it goes down from the beginning to the end? And how is that different or surprising compared to other German sentences in your perception?

Answer (score 2):

Falling intonation is the standard intonation pattern in German. There doesn't have to be a special reason to use this pattern for either the sentence end or for marking the end of an important item within the sentence.

In contrary, rising intonation means to alert the listener. If it happens at the end of the sentence, the sentence is a question.

> Da kommst du zum Bahnhof. *(falling intonation at the end)*
>
> Da kommst du zum Bahnhof? *(rising intonation at the end)*

Within the sentence:

> Und obwohl ich es ihm erklärt hatte, fand er den Bahnhof nicht.

Here you could rise at *wohl* and *klärt* to put a special alert on these facts.